# How to link image from autoform to user collection in CollectionFS for displaying a profile picture?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

Using autoform I saved the user's profile pic that they uploaded into the "images" collection. However I do not know how to call for that specific picture to be loaded on a template. The following does not display the image on the template. However if I change `Images.find({'doc.metadata.ownerId':Meteor.userId()});` to `Images.find()`, then all the images load, but I cannot specify which one I want.

```
this.Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("Images", {})]
});

Images.files.before.insert(function(doc) {
  doc.metadata = {
    date: Date.now(),
    ownerId: this.userId
             };
  console.log("before", doc);
  return doc;
});

Template.photos.helpers({
      Images: function () {
        Images.find({'doc.metadata.ownerId':Meteor.userId()});
                }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing is the images uploaded by the user, you are adding the userid as a meta value and storing it. It will only let you fetch all images uploaded by the user. Since you are also using a timestamp, the latest one would be the newest profile picture.

Alternatively, in the user document, add a `photo` field to the `profile`.

This way, when the user uploads a photo, set the `photo` value to the key of the image that was uploaded and to display the photo, you could do a

`Images.findOne({ _id: Meteor.user().profile.photo })`

If you use autoform, the storing image ID in `profile.photo` will be a lot easier.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Template.photos.helpers({
  Images: function () {
    Images.find({'metadata.ownerId':Meteor.userId()});
  }
});
```

Comment: This also did not work, I am going to try another autoform file upload package